# Dropping tables

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can I drop tables most easily from GAE datastore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There no such thing as dropping table in GAE. If you want to delete all the entities of a kind. select all the records of the kind. Use a for loop and delete them using delete(). Still you can use your admin console to delete your records. But you cannot delete all the entities of a kind at a time in admin console. Appengine sdk has its own admin console available for the localhost which is accesible at `https://localhost:8080/_ah/admin`.

Comment: Where is this delete() method? I use JPA and tried EntityManager.remove(), unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @pcjuzer On java you used use   pm.deletePersistent(e);

Comment: @Abdul Yep, it's JDO not JPA.

Comment: @pcjuzer i think in JPA you should use something like this to delete getEntityManager().remove(entity);

Comment: @Abdul Thanx, I tried remove() earlier but unfortunately it doesn't work. I also tried delete JPQL (delete from Kind where...) and it's the same. I think I seriously miss the point. Maybe the HTTP session, which triggers this code, should be authenticated?

Comment: @pcjuzer if it's not working what exactly is the error. Do some logging to check if entity exists.

Comment: @Abdul It was just my mistake: typo. Delete JPQL is working even for bulk remove.

Answer (score 7):

The datastore is schemaless, and doesn't have tables. Instead, each entity has a kind name, which is simply a string that distinguishes that entity from other kinds. If you want to delete all the records of a kind, you can use the Datastore Admin tool to do it, as documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin.html#Deleting_Entities_in_Bulk). Note that doing so will use your app's quota, the same as deleting them yourself - but it will likely be more efficient and faster than a solution you devise yourself.

Comment: The builtin seems good but how can I use it with Java instead of Python?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this, All you need to do is enable datastore admin and select the table and delete all data.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#enabling_datastore_admin_for_an_application

Answer (score 0):

- Ok, there are no tables just Kinds, but the question is similar: I want to delete many entities, but rather I want to delete the metadata of the Kind itself.
- There is a solution for bulk delete which mentioned by Nick Johnson but I didn't find how can I use it with Java and `appengine-web.xml`.
- Abdul advised to select all entities of a Kind and delete them from code one by one. It works but suboptimal since I have to use many Datastore calls. I tried it, it was expensive in terms of Datastore usage. But the idea is sensible: I have to open an administration backdoor in my application to do this. No way to open some DB tool, connect to the GAE datastore and write SQL commands.
- My final solution was in JPA using **delete query**. For example: `DELETE FROM MyKind t WHERE t.someProperty=someValue`. I wrote 'where' clause just for an example. This query should be invoked with `executeUpdate()` which returns the number of deleted entities.
- Any of the answers didn't mention that if I delete all entities of a Kind, the Kind itself (the metadata) disappears from the Datastore.
- It's OK to create another Kind later with the same name and completely different fields.
- Note that when you delete all entities of a Kind, you can't create new instances of that in admin console, or at least I couldn't find the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine's admin provides a simple UI to delete all the rows in a table.

First, turn on the Datastore Admin: go to Application Settings and enable Datastore Admin.

Now, "Datastore Admin" will be present in the main menu (under the Data section). Select it and your Entities will be listed. You can select any Entity and choose "Delete Entries" (or Backup Entities and "Copy to Another App").

Note: these options will count against your usage quota.

Answer (score -1):

Here is answer

Go to https://appengine.google.com/ then sign in to your goole app engine account.

now go to yourappengineproject --> Datastore Viewer --> Query.

now click on options you will get Query editor. type query `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name` and click on Run Query.

This way you can delete your table on app engine.

Comment: That is not a valid GQL query. The concept of "truncation" does not exist in the DataStore.